# Unable to exit nested while loops

Tags: python, while-loop, nested, simulation

I am writing a program that tracks populations given birth and death rates.
Each cell of the population is a 'dictionary' object that contains information about the cell.
The process is stochastic with exponential arrivals times.
At each arrival, the cell either produces a child or dies. These probabilities are given.
I want to loop over the entire population (`cells`) and add to the same list (`cells`) over which I am iterating.
So, I used a `while True:` loop which only breaks when some time limit (`max_t`) is reached.
Additionally, the cells which have died should no longer participate in the simulation so their `status` is changed to `'d'`. The loop only takes cells with `status == 'l'`.

The issue is the loop goes on forever and I am unable to exit it.
Can anyone explain why ?

```
''' after each birth add copy of parent to cells so it stays in loop'''

import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import bernoulli

def sim_pop(birth, death, init, max_t, max_j):

  p = birth/(birth + death)  

  time = [0]
  first = {'gen':1, 'parent':None, 'id':'1', 'status':'l', 'path':'1', 'time_born':0, 'time_alive':0, 'time_path':[0]}
  cells = [first]
  j = init
  pop = [j]

  
  flag = True
  while flag:
    for c in cells:
      
      if c['time_born'] > max_t:
        flag = False
        break  

      else:
        if c['status'] == 'l':
          t = np.random.exponential(1/((birth+death))) 
          time.append(t)

          pp = bernoulli.rvs(p)
          if pp == 1:
              j = j+1
              pop.append(j)
              n = [i for i in cells if i['parent'] == c['id']]      ## number of offpsring of c, siblings of new
              ii = str(len(n) + 1)      
              new = {'gen':c['gen']+1, 'parent':c['id'], 'id':c['id'] + '->' + ii, 'status':'l', 'path':c['path']+ '->' + ii, 'time_born':c['time_born']+t,'time_alive':0, 'time_path':c['time_path']+[c['time_born']+t]}
              cells.append(new)
              ## add copy of original so it doesn't get removed from the for loop
              copy = c.copy()
              copy['time_alive'] = c['time_alive']+t

              c['status'] = 'd'
              cells.append(copy)
              
          else:
            j = j-1
            pop.append(j)
            c['status'] = 'd'   ## change status to dead
            c['time_path'] = c['time_path']+[c['time_born']+t]    ## add time of death to time path
            
          break
        break

           
  times = [i for i in np.cumsum(time)]
  alive = [i for i in cells if i['status'] == 'l']
  dead = [i for i in cells if i['status'] == 'd']

  return times, cells, alive, dead, pop

birth = 0.009
death = 0.003
init = 1

max_t = 1000
max_j = 50000000

times, cells, alive, dead, pop = sim_pop(birth, death, init, max_t, max_j)

print(f'end population = {pop[-1]}')
print(f'cells alive = {len(alive)}')
print(f'cells dead = {len(dead)}')  ## remove dupliactes
```

Comment: If I were to take a guess, I would imagine the manipulation of your array during iteration is probably leading to the infinite loop. In general, it's *never* good practice to manipulate the array you're currently iterating.

Comment: You have two issues here: incorrect break statements which prevent you from iteratively going through all the cells, and an edge case where all the cells die and no progress can be made. I have updated my solution to account for both of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the break statements at the end of your for loop. Yes, it is typically bad to modify an array you are iterating over, but in this case your issue is you were never getting to the cells with the `time_born > max_t` because you broke out of the for loop after the first cell every iteration.

Edit: you actually have another bug. Sometimes all of the cells die but the while loop will continue forever because none of them have a `time_born` which exceeds `max_t`. I have added a check for this.

```
''' after each birth add copy of parent to cells so it stays in loop'''

import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import bernoulli

def sim_pop(birth, death, init, max_t, max_j):

  p = birth/(birth + death)  

  time = [0]
  first = {'gen':1, 'parent':None, 'id':'1', 'status':'l', 'path':'1', 'time_born':0, 'time_alive':0, 'time_path':[0]}
  cells = [first]
  j = init
  pop = [j]

  
  flag = True
  while flag:
    all_dead = True
    new_cells = cells.copy()
    for c in cells:
      if c['time_born'] > max_t:
        flag = False
        break  

      else:
        if c['status'] == 'l':
          all_dead = False
          t = np.random.exponential(1/((birth+death))) 
          time.append(t)

          pp = bernoulli.rvs(p)
          if pp == 1:
              j = j+1
              pop.append(j)
              n = [i for i in cells if i['parent'] == c['id']]      ## number of offpsring of c, siblings of new
              ii = str(len(n) + 1)      
              new = {'gen':c['gen']+1, 'parent':c['id'], 'id':c['id'] + '->' + ii, 'status':'l', 'path':c['path']+ '->' + ii, 'time_born':c['time_born']+t,'time_alive':0, 'time_path':c['time_path']+[c['time_born']+t]}
              new_cells.append(new)
              ## add copy of original so it doesn't get removed from the for loop
              copy = c.copy()
              copy['time_alive'] = c['time_alive']+t

              c['status'] = 'd'
              new_cells.append(copy)
              
          else:
            j = j-1
            pop.append(j)
            c['status'] = 'd'   ## change status to dead
            c['time_path'] = c['time_path']+[c['time_born']+t]    ## add time of death to time path
    cells = new_cells
    if all_dead:
        break

           
  times = [i for i in np.cumsum(time)]
  alive = [i for i in cells if i['status'] == 'l']
  dead = [i for i in cells if i['status'] == 'd']

  return times, cells, alive, dead, pop

birth = 0.009
death = 0.003
init = 1

max_t = 1000
max_j = 50000000

times, cells, alive, dead, pop = sim_pop(birth, death, init, max_t, max_j)

print(f'end population = {pop[-1]}')
print(f'cells alive = {len(alive)}')
print(f'cells dead = {len(dead)}')  ## remove dupliactes
```

Comment: I want to add, that when debugging the original code each iteration of the while loop, the cells list grows. But after a few iterations the first element in the cells list has the status `d` and from then on nothing changes anymore because you take that first element as `c` in the first loop go to the first else (time_born still low) and not in the nested if (status = `d`), then you break out of the for-loop and proceed with the next while-iteration without anything being changed thus your infinite loop. So yes the break-statements at the end seem misplaced to me too.

Comment: I tried removing the breaks from the for loop. Still same problem. Stuck inside the while loop. The strange thing is in some instances it does work. But I when I simulate multiple times it inevitably gets stuck.

Comment: @kymset Try refreshing your page and copying the new code I have posted, I explain in my edited post why it sometimes used to get stuck.

Comment: amazing. You are right. It works using all_dead. And it's way faster than I had hoped. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that all your break statements are inside `for c in cells:` and break this loop, and the while loop keeps going.

You need another break statement that is outside the `for c in cells:` loop, or to check your indentation.

Comment: That is what the flag is meant for. It breaks out of the while loop when the flag is set to false.

Comment: Yes, but if `break` is within a nested loop, it'll break out of the deepest loop that it lives in. To exit outer loops multiple `break` are needed

Comment: That's the point, he doesn't use a break for exiting the while loop and he doesn't need to. He just sets the flag to False which then stops the while-loop on the next iteration. My first comment was misleading in that regard, the flag doesn't break out of the while loop directly, but stops its continuation on the next iteration.

Comment: I understand now. Yes, thats a good fix.   
I aimed just to explain why the loop didn't break, not how to fix it.